# Batch file to add multiple registry values to single key

Tags: batch-file, registry, regedit

I have an issue with merging (writing) reg values to a single key in bat.
The purpose is to use this bat as a logon script so i dont have to keep pushing the script.

This is what I'm trying to get into the reg:

```
"HKCU\Software\SAP\NWBC\Settings\Pages\RuntimeConnections\BAG_1BC8D0D7E86C3C468F1A2F947453D983" 
"NAME"="Process Integration Development"
"URL"="<server URL>"
"CLIENT"="100"
"LANGUAGE"="EN"
```

I have at least 20 or so of these RuntimeConnections that i need in the reg. Each key (BAG_1BC8D0D7E86C3C468F1A2F947453D983) has 3-5 values that need to be added (name, URL, client, language, user).

I have tried:

```
reg add "HKCU\Software\SAP\NWBC\Settings\Pages\RuntimeConnections\BAG_1BC8D0D7E86C3C468F1A2F947453D983" /v "NAME" /t "REG_DWORD" /d "Process Integration Development"
```

that works for the first value but not the second, third, fourth, etc. If I do it for each value it over wrights the previous value. Would I be able to do this with RegIni?

Any ideas, comments, concerns, questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this works here:

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL disableDelayedExpansion
reg add "HKCU\Software\SAP\NWBC\Settings\Pages\RuntimeConnections\BAG_1BC8D0D7E86C3C468F1A2F947453D983"
reg add "HKCU\Software\SAP\NWBC\Settings\Pages\RuntimeConnections\BAG_1BC8D0D7E86C3C468F1A2F947453D983" /v "NAME" /d "Process Integration Development"
reg add "HKCU\Software\SAP\NWBC\Settings\Pages\RuntimeConnections\BAG_1BC8D0D7E86C3C468F1A2F947453D983" /v "URL" /d "server URL"
reg add "HKCU\Software\SAP\NWBC\Settings\Pages\RuntimeConnections\BAG_1BC8D0D7E86C3C468F1A2F947453D983" /v "CLIENT" /d "100" /t REG_DWORD
reg add "HKCU\Software\SAP\NWBC\Settings\Pages\RuntimeConnections\BAG_1BC8D0D7E86C3C468F1A2F947453D983" /v "LANGUAGE" /d "EN"
```

session protocol:

```
C:\Users\Endoro>reg query "HKCU\Software\SAP\NWBC\Settings\Pages\RuntimeConnections\BAG_1BC8D0D7E86C3C468F1A2F947453D983"

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\SAP\NWBC\Settings\Pages\RuntimeConnections\BAG_1BC8D0D7E86C3C468F1A2F947453D983
    (Default)    REG_SZ
    NAME    REG_SZ    Process Integration Development
    URL    REG_SZ    server URL
    CLIENT    REG_DWORD    0x64
    LANGUAGE    REG_SZ    EN
```

Comment: Can you explain to me how this works? Is it the &setlocal or disabledDelayedExpansion?

Comment: @Benny please look at `reg add /?` and `setlocal /?`.

Comment: I have seen the reg add but I didnt know about setlocal, thank you